# How can I start my baseAdapter from a different index?

Tags: android, baseadapter

Right now my baseAdapter starts from 0, I need it to start from 1.

I know this question has been answered before, however, I tried changing the getItem to return 1 and getItemId to return 1 and set listView.setSelection(1);

But it doesn't change anything.

I need my adpter to start at position=1 instead of position=0

position=1,

position=2,

position=3... etc.

instead of

position=0,

position=1,

position=2... etc

adaptor

```
package com.example.zdroa.fetchmovies;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.TreeMap;

class ListViewAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private TreeMap<Integer, String> urls;
    private TreeMap<Integer, String> titles;


    ListViewAdaptor(Context context, TreeMap<Integer, String> URLS, TreeMap<Integer, String> TITLES) {
        mContext = context;
        urls = URLS;
        titles = TITLES;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.results_layout, null);
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPosters);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.results_layout_tv_movie_name);

        Drawable d = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.place_holder_img);


        String link_end = urls.ceilingEntry(position).getValue();
        String title = titles.ceilingEntry(position).getValue();

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + link_end)
                .placeholder(d)
                .into(imageView);

        textView.setText(title);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

fragmentactivity

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);
    listView.setSelection(1);

    new ImageLoadTask().execute();

    //if fragment is visible
    if (getActivity() != null) {


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println(TITLES.ceilingEntry(position).getValue());
            }
        });
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: did you try listView.scrolltoposition(1)

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i'm sorry. my question was unclear. when the adapter itterates through the positions, instead of starting at index 0 i want it to start from 1, so, position=1, position=2, position=3... etc. instead of position=0, position=1, position=2... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it,

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.size() - 1;
}
```

change it too, hope it will work for you..

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.results_layout, null);
            }
            position = position + 1;
            if(urls.size() >= position)
            {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPosters);
                TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.results_layout_tv_movie_name);

                Drawable d = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.place_holder_img);


                String link_end = urls.ceilingEntry(position).getValue();
                String title = titles.ceilingEntry(position).getValue();

                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + link_end)
                        .placeholder(d)
                        .into(imageView);

                textView.setText(title);

            }

            return convertView;
        }
```